# Can the code within a <script runat=server> read form values which are posted by a form which doesn't have runat=server attribute?

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms, runatserver, runat

I want to post a form on html and process the variables with asp.net code, like writing a php code. do I have to use <%  %> or can I create an empty file with

```
<script runat=server>

</script>
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Do you want to generate the HTML using code or do you want to write a regular HTML form and process the request in the server?

Comment: @JotaBe I want to process the request coming from a form which is not a runat=Server form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the postback values using the Request.Form.

This exposes all the input values in properties.

Look at this:

[HttpRequest.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx)

If you have an iput with id "name", you can read the user input like so:

```
  Request.Form["name"]
```

The result is always a string, so that you'll need to parse it to convert it to another data type.